# Error running java programs

Tags: java

Every program I run in java gives similiar error.

This is a helloworld program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloworld (wrong nam
e: helloworldapp)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: helloworld.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Can you also show your code? And explain how you run it?

Comment: helloworldapp or helloworld or HelloWorld? Note, that Java treats class names sentive to upper/lower. Editor=Notepad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Read [this tutorial](http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html) about this problem.

Comment: When i tried this code it showed error on the class keyword while compiling. So i deleted the public keyword and compiled it successfully. When i run the pgm i get the same output.. :(

Comment: Hey, it seems like a classpath issue, are you using an IDE or simple text editor? Read this article it describes exactly your problem: http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html

Answer (score 4):

The class file `helloworld.class` contains a class called `helloworldapp.class`. The only real reason for this that I can think of is that you manually renamed the `.class` file.

That won't work! A class called `helloworldapp` must be found in a `.class` file called `helloworldapp.class`.

If you want to change the name of the class, rename the `.java` source file, edit the `class` definition and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the Java program? Are you passing the arguments correctly? Pay attention to the class path. If you have helloworld.java file and have compiled it to helloworld.class, you should run it like this (from a command prompt in the same directory the class file is located):

```
java -cp . helloworld
```

Comment: at first i have set path for java compiler as " path=%path%;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin " . The program is'nt showing the msg Hello world!..

Comment: You need first to compile the file (javac HelloWorld.java). This will produce a HelloWorld.class file. Then you can run it with the command in my answer.

Comment: You don't use a trailing or leading blank here: `" path=%path%;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin "`, do you? Or lowercase 'path' instead of PATH? You have to be precise in programming.

Comment: This isn't a path issue! Read the error message! The `.class` file is found, but contains a class with the wrong name!